# Missing Rotate Animation attributes

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm reading Android Developer's API Guides and particularly the guide about the [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

The example in this page makes use, among others, of a `rotate` element :

```
   <rotate
       android:fromDegrees="0"
       android:toDegrees="-45"
       android:toYScale="0.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:startOffset="700"
       android:duration="400" />
```

One of the tags is `toYscale`. What I don't understand is how it is a valid attribute since it's not  included both in [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html#inhattrs) class or in the [R.styleable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#ScaleAnimation_toYScale).

Shouldn't that attribute appear in the class reference ? 
Unless I have to check somewhere else for all the supported attributes by `rotate` element?

Any pointers ?

Comment: I think that might have been a type. You don't need a toYScale attribute in a rotation animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [@W.K.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821110/w-k-s),  it is most likely a typo from whoever was making the docs because:

- The full name of the `R.styleable` attribute is `R.styleable.ScaleAnimation_toYScale`.

If it weren't specific to `ScaleAnimation`, it would not have been named as such **especially because** `RotateAnimation` *does not* extend `ScaleAnimation`.

- The source code of [`RotateAnimation`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.java) does not use `toYScale`, only `pivotY`

```
public RotateAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.RotateAnimation);

    mFromDegrees = a.getFloat(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.RotateAnimation_fromDegrees, 0.0f);
    mToDegrees = a.getFloat(com.android.internal.R.styleable.RotateAnimation_toDegrees, 0.0f);

    Description d = Description.parseValue(a.peekValue(
        com.android.internal.R.styleable.RotateAnimation_pivotX));
    mPivotXType = d.type;
    mPivotXValue = d.value;

    d = Description.parseValue(a.peekValue(
        com.android.internal.R.styleable.RotateAnimation_pivotY));
    mPivotYType = d.type;
    mPivotYValue = d.value;

    a.recycle();

    initializePivotPoint();
}
```

When in doubt, you can always check to see if `android:toYScale=` actually *does something* when used in `<rotate>`. The docs have mistakes in them, they were generated by humans after all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I checked the code too, but I wasn't sure and I had to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`android:toYScale` is ending Y size offset.

[Read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) (View Animation's Tween animation section) for more information.